# ARSCNView as VRView

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, virtual-reality, arscnview

Long things short:

I want make my iOS application Mac friendly. In my case I want (I don‘t know how to do) to use my ARSCNViews as an view that presents me everything in VR.
I don‘t want to have any special room. I only want to show SCNNodes.

*Short:*
I have got an ARSCNView so I see things in AR,

*but I want to see the things(SCNNodes) **in VR**, so that the users don’t have to continue using camera.

> I want to see make an VRView from my AR(*SCN*)View.

**I couldn‘t find any information how to do that.**

*I tried hard for 4 days.*

Does somebody know how to do that?

***Thanks***

**PS:**

I already tried:

> create a new camera

> Use some **not** helpful code from *Stackoverflow* and * Dev Documentation*
> Like Stereo

> Tried to create to ARSCNViews to give one as the input for the other on *(I gave the first non camera input*

> *(Something really stupid)* I wanted to use an SCN

Comment: I dont't really understand what you are trying to achive. Can you explain your request more precisely?

Comment: I updated it a little bit. Sorry, my English might be really bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for `nonAR` (a.k.a. VR) app is to use [SCNView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview).